# MySQL table query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a MySQL table query which will return a table to populate a multiline Google Chart. At the moment i am doing this with a combination of MySQL and PHP.

The application is a remote data logging system which pulls data from multiple devices over multiple sites and store the result in one table.

I have two tables in a Database:

Table 1 Devices (a record of each device in the system)

```
| Deviceid | Location | Site |
________________________
| 1        | Entrance | 1
| 2        | Area 1   | 1
| 3        | Area 2   | 2
| 4        | Area 3   | 2
| 5        | Area 4   | 1
```

Table 2 DeviceData (a record of the data sent from each device with a time stamp)

```
| id | DeviceID | Site | Data | Time Received
_____________________________________________
| 1  | 1        |  1   | 240  | 12:02
| 2  | 1        |  1   | 230  | 12:28
| 3  | 3        |  2   | 21   | 12:28
| 4  | 2        |  1   | 231  | 12:28
| 5  | 4        |  2   | 99   | 12.40
| 6  | 5        |  1   | 121  | 12.45
```

I want to run a query which will produce a tabulated result for each site such as

```
| Device 1 | Device 2 | Device 3 | Time Received
|  240     |          |          | 12:02
|  230     |  231     |          | 12:28
|          |          | 12.45    | 12:45
```

I cant then use this tabulated data to populate a google chart.

At the moment i am achieving this by running 2 queries and PHP

```
SELECT DeviceId from Devices WHERE Site = X
```

and then using the results of that query, run a second query inside a PHP for-loop using the Device Id returned to search for each device's data and then using this data to populate a PHP array.

It is working, but it feels clunky and i suspect that there is a more elegant solution just using MySQL.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with single query and re-arrange data in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join

```
SELECT Devices.*, DeviceData.*
from Devices 
INNER JOIN DeviceData  on Devices.site = DeviceData.site

WHERE Devices.Site = X
```

Answer (score 0):

I can advice next PHP solution:

```
<?php
$site = 1;

$query = "SELECT Devices.*, DeviceData.*
FROM Devices
INNER JOIN DeviceData  on Devices.site = DeviceData.site
WHERE Devices.Site = ?;";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $site, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function($res, $d) {
        if (!isset($res[$d['TimeReceived']])) {
            $res[$d['TimeReceived']] = [
                'TimeReceived' => $d['TimeReceived']
            ];
        }
        $res[$d['TimeReceived']]['Device_' . $d['DeviceID']] = $d['Data'];
        
        return $res;
    },
    []
);

print_r($result);
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=21242c3281f5d03af5028d035ff4c961&sqlses=3f8c1831b7cc0271a97325db94132dce&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Result;

```
Array
(
    [12:02:00] => Array
        (
            [TimeReceived] => 12:02:00
            [Device_1] => 240
        )

    [12:28:00] => Array
        (
            [TimeReceived] => 12:28:00
            [Device_1] => 230
            [Device_2] => 231
        )

    [12:45:00] => Array
        (
            [TimeReceived] => 12:45:00
            [Device_5] => 121
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks fro your advice. Ill try this and get back to you. Much appreciated